# 400 Bad Request in LUIS: Cannot find the specified subscription

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a LUIS app using the LUIS programmatic API. After the app is successfully created and trained, I want to assign an API key to the app using this endpoint:

```
PUT /luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/assignedkey
```

Both my programmatic API key (obtained from luis.ai) and the normal API key (the one I am trying to assign, obtained from Azure Portal) are registered to the same email address.

However, when I am trying to send a request to the above endpoint, it fails with this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Cannot find the specified subscription"
  }
}
```

I'm out of ideas for what I might be doing wrong, because exactly the same logic already worked before.

Is there some kind of way to "assign" an Azure subscription to my LUIS account?

**Update**:

I didn't find an answer to my question, but I found a workaround. Calling `PUT /luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/settings` will set the application to "public", which means you can use any subscription key with it. See [docs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/58aeface39e2bb03dcd5909e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this endpoint is now deprecated because I get the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "DeprecatedException",
        "message": "To assign a subscription key to an app, please go to the LUIS website at https://www.luis.ai and assign it from the app publish page."
    }
}
```

In the luis page I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint PUT */luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/assignedkey* and */luis/api/v2.0/subscriptions* are indeed deprecated. I contacted to LUIS support and they answered:

> We are shifting the key management experience to happen only through the portal. Users no longer need to copy and paste keys, we offer a well-integrated experience that lists all the Azure keys inside our portal, key management details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys).